# CreatedAtRoute: System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I don't really understand what is going on, and tried all sort of suggestions from other questions on Stack Overflow, such as using the `ActionName` attribute, passing `SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false` to `AddControllers`, using `CreatedAtAction` instead. The code seems pretty conventional for an ASP.NET Core REST API, so I don't really understand what is going on here, no matter what I do I get the `No route matches the supplied values` response, and the resource is added. Can it have something to do with .NET 6's insistence on explicitly declaring types as nullable?

```
[HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
[ActionName(nameof(GetProduct))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public ActionResult<ProductDto> GetProduct([FromQuery] Guid productId)
{
    var product = _productRepository.GetProductById(productId);

    return product is not null
        ? Ok(_mapper.Map<ProductDto>(product))
        : NotFound();
}

[HttpPost]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public ActionResult<ProductDto> CreateProduct(
    [FromBody] ProductCreateDto product)
{
    var productEntity = _mapper.Map<Product>(product);

    _productRepository.CreateProduct(productEntity);

    var productDto = _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(productEntity);

    return CreatedAtRoute(
        nameof(GetProduct),
        new { productId = productDto.Id },
        productDto);
}
```

Comment: Is it perhaps that your route expects "id", but your method takes "productId"? When you pass the route values to `CreatedAtRoute` you call it "productId" too.

Comment: Tried both `id` and `Id` to no avail.

Comment: So you changed `CreatedAtRoute` to use `id = productDto.Id` and you changed `[FromQuery] Guid productId` to `[FromRoute] Guid id`, right?

Comment: Yes, all possible variations :)

Comment: Oddly, `[HttpGet("{id:guid}", Name = nameof(GetProduct))]` works. `[ActionName(nameof(GetProduct))]` does not. I'm not really sure why, unless `ActionNameAttribute` isn't intended for WebAPI. ‍♂️

Comment: Other things I've tried: 

* Provide other methods with a unique `ActionName` 
* Explicitly declaring productDto as `ProductDto` rather than making the compiling infer its type as `ProductDto?`

The controller's route is declared as `"api/[controller]"`, can this possibly be related?

Comment: Also tried removing the `:guid` constraint.

Comment: `[HttpGet("{id:guid}" Name = nameof(GetProduct))]` was the first thing I did, then I read some solutions from people that they solved the issue using the `ActionName` attribute, so I did that. I tried the `Name` clause again, this time also providing my other HttpGet (getAll) with a unique `Name = nameof(GetProducts)` clause (might be conflicting with the getById?). I must say, I'm really not happy with this `new {}` anonymous type in a strongly typed language like C#.

Comment: It may have been the first thing you did, but did you also correct `id` and `[FromQuery]` to `productId` and `[FromRoute]` respectively? Because that certainly solved the problem in my own tests. [This](https://pastebin.com/fNqRUJLK) works for me 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a giddy goat. The solution was to change `"{id:guid}"` to `"{productId:guid}"`:

```
[HttpGet("{productId:guid}", Name = nameof(GetProduct))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public ActionResult<ProductDto> GetProduct([FromRoute] Guid productId)
{
    var product = _productRepository.GetProductById(productId);

    return product is not null
        ? Ok(_mapper.Map<ProductDto>(product))
        : NotFound();
}
```

Thanks DiplomacyNotWar for rubber-ducking!

Comment: It really is weird that I couldn't get it working with `[ActionName(nameof(GetProduct))]`. Both end up being exactly the same in the list of action descriptors, so it's weird. I'm glad you got it working anyway.